# Linearity of differential of vector-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In Baby Rudin, Rudin states:

> Definition 9.11: Suppose $E$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ $f$ maps $E$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$, and $x\in E$. If there exists a linear transformation $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\lvert f(x+h) - f(x) + Ah\rvert}{\lvert h\rvert} = 0,$$ then we say that $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and we write $f'(x) = A$.

My confusion stems from the last line. The derivative of a function isn't necessarily
linear (say, for example, $g(x) = x^3$ and $g'(x) =3x^2$). So, when Rudin says $f'(x) = A$, I take it that he doesn't mean the derivative of $f$ is linear. What exactly does he mean then?

I know that $A$ is called the differential so $f'(x) = A$ is the differential of $f$ at $x$, I suppose. Is the differential distinct from the derivative then, since the former is, by requirement, linear while the latter need not be linear?

Comment: The derivative is a linear map. When we work in the reals we are sloppy, and say that, for example, the derivative of $f(x)=x^2$ at $x=1$ is $f'(1) = 2$, but we should really think of it as a linear map, $h \mapsto 2h$.

Comment: @copper.hat I understand why this is the case for $x^2$, since we're taught that, for $f(x) = x^2$, the derivative is $f'(x) = 2x$. But, take the case where $g(x) = x^3$ and then $g'(x) = 3x^2$. We then have a map $h\to 3h^2$, which isn't linear. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: I was not clear. In your cubic example, the derivative is the map $h \mapsto 3x^2 h$. In the reals there is no advantage to the distinction, but in other spaces is it essential.

Comment: As an example, if you take the space of matrices, and the function $f(X) = X^2$, then the derivative is the linear map $H \mapsto XH +HX$. We cannot write this map as a simple multiplication of a matrix.

Comment: For any real valued function, the derivative is the linear map $h \mapsto f'(x) h$.

Comment: @Obamafish At every point, the derivative produces a *function*, not a number. This is not what you're taught in calculus at first, but it is true. Yes, what is sometimes referred to as a differential is the derivative in more general spaces. We denote the number because it's conceptually easier, and we can plot it! When dealing with functions from $\Bbb{R}^m$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$, we can similarly get around treating them as functions by representing these linear functions by $m \times n$ real matrices. But, outside of $\Bbb{R}^n$, often we have no other options than to treat it as a function.

Comment: @copper.hat I really appreciate all your comments, they help a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion arises because you think of the derivative as a function which matches to each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the slope of its tangent $f'(x)$. You are right that *this* function does not need to be linear; for instance, if $f(x)=x^3$, then $f'(x)=3x^2$.

*However*, consider a fixed point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$. The derivative which in calculus we think of as a number, can also be thought of as a function which associates to every $x$-increment the $y$-increment of its tangent at $x_0$. For instance, for $f(x)=x^3$ at $x_0=1$ the derivative is $2$; the associated function is $y=2x$. For another example, at $x_0=5$ the derivative is $75$; the associated function is $y=75x$. The meaning of these functions is that to a certain approximation, $f(x)$ behaves roughly like the linear function $y=75x$ around $x_0=5$, and so on. Note that all these functions $y=2x, y=75x$, etc, are linear!

So in calculus we usually think of the derivative at $x_0$ as a number $f'(x_0)$ (the slope of the tangent), and not as this function $y=f'(x_0)x$. The function $y=f'(x_0)x$ is instead called [the differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function).

In multivariate calculus the same thing is going on. The differential is the linear map that in a sense best approximates the function near a given point. So the multivariate differential generalizes the single-variable differential. (We may still speak of the matrix which represents this linear map; and then this matrix, called the Jacobian, is the generalization of the usual single variable derivative.)

The text you're reading is using the notation $f'(x_0)$ to denote the linear map $x_0 \mapsto Ax_0$, so in that sense they are using $f'(x_0)$ as a generalization of the single-variable differential, rather than the single-variable derivative.

It is the differential which is a linear map, and this is true simply by its definition: it is multiplication by a matrix. This is the function which is the best linear approximation for the original function, *at a single given point*. The function which outputs the different Jacobian matrices for every *varying input point* is definitely not necessarily linear.